# How to test UI and other elements of a universal swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode

I have made a framework which I am getting in my application through cocoapods. It contains storyboards, viewcontrollers and REST api calls via alamofire. What would be the best way to write unit and UI tests for it as well as ensure code coverage.

Comment: Xcode has XCTestCase as part of the Xcode project. Might be a good point to test.

Comment: I am using this framework as a pod. While creating a pod library it gives me an option of quick which seemed different from xctestcase (I am new to this). So what should be a good path I should take up for this

Comment: Quick is a framework for testing. In my opinion I would prefer to use what Xcode offers (XCTestCase) unless I see a limitation for it. As part of the framework that you have created there would be a test target and you can create XCTestCase for it. Having your framework available through cocoa pods doesn't change the scenario.

Comment: Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html